# Asp.Net core web API anti-forgery validation fails if used along with JWT bearer authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, x-xsrf-token

I am trying to use Anti-forgery along with jwt bearer authentication in Asp.net core 3.0 web API. The weird problem that I am facing is that anti-forgery works perfectly fine, but if I try to add an `[Authorize]` filter to the controller action along with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, then `AntiForgery` validation fails with Http 400 error.

startup.cs :

```cs
services.AddCors();
services.AddControllers();
services.AddMvc();
services.AddAntiforgery
    (
    options =>
    {
        options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        options.Cookie = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieBuilder()
        { Name = "X-XSRF-COOKIE" };
    }
    );
// configure strongly typed settings objects
var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

// configure jwt authentication
var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
```

UsersController.cs :

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[HttpPost("authenticate")]
public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]AuthenticateModel model)
{
    var user = _userService.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password);
    var tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext);
    Response.Cookies.Append("X-XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = false
    });
    if (user == null)
        return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is incorrect" });

    return Ok(user);
}
```

If I use `[Authorize]` filter on this below action `Antiforgery` validation fails.If I remove it `Antiforgery` validation seems to be working fine.

UsersController.cs :

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var users = _userService.GetAll();
    return Ok(users);
}
```

and this is how I am generating JWT the token :

```cs
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), 
    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
};
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

servers logs :

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "GetAll", controller = "Users"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult GetAll() on controller WebApi.Controllers.UsersController (WebApi).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter[1]
      Antiforgery token validation failed. The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateTokens(HttpContext httpContext, AntiforgeryTokenSet antiforgeryTokenSet)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action WebApi.Controllers.UsersController.GetAll (WebApi) in 28.5729ms
```

Tried setting `HttpContext.user` before calling `_antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext)` but it did not worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup antiforgeryvalidation in the startup file before going into controller. See the below code snippet:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.Value;

        if (
            string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
            string.Equals(path, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // The request token can be sent as a JavaScript-readable cookie, 
            // and Angular uses it by default.
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, 
                new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        }

        return next(context);
    });
}
```

Comment: For further detail, you can view: You can view the link for further details:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1